# Не работает сайт по сертификату, выданный от внутреннего ЦС на Windows

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, certificate

Уже бьюсь несколько дней. Ситуация простая. Есть домен mnivea.ru. Есть тестовый сайт на apache2 на Linux машине Ubuntu - site1.mnivea.ru. Необходимо что бы он работал по SSL сертификату по одному имени site1.mnivea.ru, а не по 80 порту. Что сделал: Сгенерировал запрос и отправил его содержимое на корпоративный ЦС, который на windows Server.

```
sudo req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mnivea_ru.key -out mnivea_ru.csr
```

И сразу здесь сомнения - как нужно называть ключ и запрос сертификата? (я назвал через нижн подчеркивание, в документации пишут обязательно как доменное имя, где то вообще видел FQDN, то есть mnivea.ru.key или вообще  site1.mnivea.ru.key?)

Короче далее, выданный сертификат от ЦС openssl конвертировал в *.crt

```
x509 -inform DER -in certnew.cer -out mnivea_ru.crt
```

Итог, имеем 2 файла: mnivea_ru.key и mnivea_ru.crt. Редактирую /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf и вставляю строки:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.key
```

Перезагрузка systemctl restart apache2 проходит успешно. Начинаю проверять сайт с windows машины, прежде устанавливаю сертификат самого ЦС. И - ошибка сертификата, замок перечеркнут. Проверяю (есть почтовый сервер в этом же домене mail.mnivea.ru) открывается без ругани, то есть сертификат от ЦС правильный и установлен!
Но, открываю сайт site1.mnivea.ru и ошибка сертификата. Куда копать?? Где я допускаю ошибку? неправильно названы может файлы? Попробовал например добавить цепочку, склеил конечный сертификат плюс корневой от ЦС (кстати где то пишут последовательность неважна, где-то важна, у меня получилось что последовательность важна)

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.key    
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.ca-bundle
```

Не помогло. Потом добавил просто еще один сертификат только от ЦС

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mnivea_ru.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/CA.crt
```

Не помогло.
Еще момент, у меня есть коммерческий сертификат от GlobalSign на два имени для mnivea.ru и при его установке сайт работает! (причем, как просто ключ + конечный серт, так и ключ + конечный серт + серт от ЦС). Но не работает сертификат от корпоративного ЦС! Может нужно машину Linux правильно назвать и где то DNS имя в самой машине Linux.

Еще момент, при создании запроса сертификата обращаю внимание только на поле Common Name где указываю site.mnivea.ru Остальные - города, название организации  и т.п указываю любые, любо вообще не заполняю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему то никто не догадался ответить, что нужно использовать альтернативные имена (subjectAltName). А subject Name тут играет последнюю роль.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы загляните в сгенерированный сертификат, то вероятнее всего там будет странное доменное имя (если вообще будет). Вам нужно добавить все необходимые поля в запрос. Самый простой способ указать доменное имя сервера - задать его в поле `Common Name (CN)` поля `Subject`

Через командную строку - добавьте опцию `-subj '/CN=site1.mnivea.ru`:

```
sudo req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -subj '/CN=site1.mnivea.ru' -keyout mnivea_ru.key -out mnivea_ru.csr
```

Затем проверьте, что именно сгенерировано в запросе: `openssl req -text -noout -verify -in mnivea_ru.csr`

После того, как получите подписанный сертификат, проверьте, что там в поле `Subject`:

```
x509 -noout -text -in mnivea_ru.crt
```

Comment: Сделал с указанием только site1.mnivea.ru. То же самое, ругань на сертификат. команда x509 -noout -text -in mnivea_ru.crt показывает что успешно и в сертификате есть только CN=site1.mnivea.ru. Наверно где то фундаментальную ошибку я делаю , но как определить где -не пойму. То ли какая-то цепочка может нужна из корневого серт плюс конечный серт, не знаю.

Comment: Что еще интересно, windows утилита certutil показывает больше информации о сертификате и  разные типы сертификатов, чем из openssl. Еще, когда я генерировал много раз запрос к тому же внутреннему ЦС из windows консоли Exchange сервера (как раз для имени mail.mnivea.ru), то всё проходило гладко и сертификат от ЦС работал. Как будто openssl чего то не договаривают. Кстати, часто замечал что openssll упускают множество моментов в документации, нужно самому додумываться и догадываться. Например, вообще не говорят - "Не забудьте поставить на устройство, с которого тестируете сертификат самого ЦС".

Comment: Как будто я должен родиться с этими знаниями. Это же документация, описание должно быть От и До. Полное сопровождение.

Comment: @Oleg0341 Напишите какая именно ошибка сертификата

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Не нашел как вставить скрины. Вот файлы https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgfvDQ65okq0gcxhbEmxGovlAL6EPQ?e=a5BXda  Здесь три скрина (ругань на сертификат) и сертификаты: закрытый/открытый ключ  (site1.crt, site1.key пароль 12345), запрос сертификата site1.csr, ответ на запрос от windows ЦС certnew.cer. Так же сюда добавил корневой сертификат CADC01.cer. Это всё тестовая среда, поэтому нестрашно. Сейчас 25-ый раз попытался сгенерировать - эффект тот же. где-то я делаю банальную ошибку.

Comment: И в файле конфигурации у меня только две строчки на файлы, которые выслал (сразу после установки apache2)


SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl/site1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl/site1.key

Comment: Почему сертификат недействителен? Покажите развёрнутую ошибку, пожалуйста

Comment: Как показать ошибку развернуто? не могу найти.